# Deployment of Google Cloud COS on Vmware Default Logins

Tags: containers, cluster-computing, vmware, google-anthos, google-container-os

I am typically new to the GC space and I am trying to run a gc container optimized OS on vmware.
The ova file that I downloaded is gke-on-prem-cos-1.28.0-gke.651.ova.
Vmware esxi version 7 update 03.

I created a VM on VMware by registering a VM using OVA/OVF file.
Upon booting, the shell asks me for logins that I do not have.

What are the default logins? Or are there any configs I can do before deployment to be authenticated?

I have tried the known linux default logins all to no success.
I have tried importing as an appliance to Oracle Virtual box but got stuck on booting (error waiting for root device).
I am currently looking to test any other google ova file to see if the challenge persists.